# Javascript Date Format Without using Intl.DateFormat

Tags: javascript

How can one convert a UTC date such as

```
2021-03-22T03:12:36.6761241+06:00 to a simple date taking the locale into account
```

For example in en-GB the above would be 16/03/2021 03:12:36

While for US user it would be 04/22/2021 03:12:36 PM.

We would prefer not to use Intl.DateFormat due to requirement of a massive number of js files in order to polyfill for older browsers.

Comment: Not wanting to use browser default object means you're asking for a tool/library?

Comment: Have you tried momentJs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use like this:

```js
let d = "2021-03-22T03:12:36.6761241+06:00";

d = new Date(d);

console.log(d.toLocaleDateString() + ' ' + d.toLocaleTimeString());
```